# im looking for a simple game lobby built in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a simple game lobby in python. I have made a small game and want to implement a lobby but have never done this. Are there any examples I can hack at?

Answer (score 1):

A lobby is little more than a glorified chat room. I would look into a chat room module in python and integrate into your game client. That would serve as a makeshift lobby.